# Targeting unmapped class error in Spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I work on basic exemplary app that is about @OneToMany & ManyToOne annotation. I define mapping between two classes, apparently there is no error but on running app it gives me an error : Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.orchard.orchard.model.AppUser.userRole[    com.orchard.orchard.model.UserRole]

I'm failed to understand where does problem lies as mapping also describe in AppUser. I'd be grateful for the help.

Classes are as follows:

AppUser.java

```
package com.orchard.orchard.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity

public class AppUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
private String name;
@Column(unique = true)
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;

@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String bio;
private Date createdDate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
 FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>();
    

public AppUser() {
    
}


public AppUser(Integer id, String name, String username, String 
  password, String email, String bio,
        Date createdDate, Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.bio = bio;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.userRole = userRoles;
}


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}


public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}


public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public String getBio() {
    return bio;
}


public void setBio(String bio) {
    this.bio = bio;
}


public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}


public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}


public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
    return userRole;
}


public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    this.userRole = userRoles;
}
}
```

UserRole.java

```
package com.orchard.orchard.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class UserRole {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long userRoleId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonIgnore
private AppUser appUser;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;


public UserRole() {
    
}

public UserRole(long userRoleId, AppUser appUser, Role role) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    this.appUser = appUser;
    this.role = role;
}

public long getUserRoleId() {
    return userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(long userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

public AppUser getAppUser() {
    return appUser;
}

public void setAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
    this.appUser = appUser;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `@Entity` annotation to your `UserRole` class

```
@Entity
public class UserRole {

}
```